# Laravel - 9 Vite with vue cli 3 - vue-router error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, vue-router, vite

I can't fixed it please help. what is the issues.
I need help. can't find out it.

Error Image Link:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run: `npm run watch`
Then move your files from `/resources/js` to `/resources/js/src`.
Then, I suggest you make your file named `route` as a `router`.
The name "components" or "views" does not matter, but I would prefer to create a folder named "views" and create "components" in it.
Then you can try to import like these according to the path you will create:

```
import Home from '../views/index.vue';
```

or

```
import Home from '../views/components/home/index.vue';
```

Finally, don't forget to run: `php artisan optimize:clear`